# Changing figure's captions

Tags: floats, captions

I need to write a report where I want all the figure's captions is the style Figure part.chapter.section. I tried to do :

```
\usepackage{chngcntr} \counterwithin{figure}{part}{chapter}
```

And it didn't worked. Does someone knows the answer?
Thanks.

Comment: Are the figure numbers supposed to be *reset* with every `\chapter` (and `\part`)?

Comment: Which document class do you use?

Answer (score 1):

By default, floats are numbered *within* `\chapter`s under the default document classes (`book` and `report`) and typically also under custom classes that support the use of `\chapter`s, so all you need to do is update the representation of the `figure` counter. To do this, add the following to your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thepart.\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
```

With such a lengthy figure numbering scheme, you may also want to increase the width allowed for these within the default LoF. [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) can help with that, adjusting `\cftfignumwidth` to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thepart.\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{3em}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\part{A part}
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{figure} \caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{figure} \caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\begin{figure} \caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{figure} \caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\begin{figure} \caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\begin{figure} \caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{figure} \caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\begin{figure} \caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\begin{figure} \caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\begin{figure} \caption{A figure} \end{figure}

\part{A part}
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{figure} \caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{figure} \caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\begin{figure} \caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{figure} \caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\begin{figure} \caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\begin{figure} \caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{figure} \caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\begin{figure} \caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\begin{figure} \caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\begin{figure} \caption{A figure} \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\counterwithin{figure}{\chapter}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thepart.\thechapter.\arabic{figure}
```

should do the trick. Are your chapter numbers reset at each new part?